# as.Date() Giving wrong output from Day of Year calculation

Tags: r, as.date

I am trying to use a dataset that uses Day of Year (DOY) and want to calculate dates:

To convert DOY format to a date I use:

```
as.Date(DOY, origin = "%Y-01-01")
```

But I seem to be getting a problem. For example: DOY = `121` for `2003`

```
as.Date(121, origin = "2003-01-01")
[1] "2003-05-02"
```

This should be: `"2003-05-01"` (see here: https://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/Craig.Markwardt/doy2003.html)

The code works for a leap year:

```
as.Date(121, origin = "2004-01-01")
[1] "2004-05-01"
```

(and shows up correctly here: https://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/Craig.Markwardt/doy2004.html)

Problem persists for `2005`.

Am I missing something obvious here or is there a problem in the code missing leap years?

Comment: as.Date is calculating the number of days after the origin, so `as.Date(1, origin = "2003-01-01")` is equal to the origin + 1 day or Jan, 2nd.  For your calculation, you will need to use December 31st as the origin.  FYI double check your calculation for the 2004 date above.

Comment: @Dave2e: Thanks, this works: `as.Date(121, origin = "2002-12-31")`, gives: `"2003-05-01"`; however `as.Date(121, origin = "2003-12-31")`, gives: `"2004-04-30"`. As in my post: `as.Date(121, origin = "2004-01-01")`, gives: `"2004-05-01"`. This doesn't seem consistent (or am I misunderstanding the logic).

Comment: 2004 is a leap year

Comment: It is consistent. Day 121 in 2004 is April 30th, not May 1st. Double check your links above.

Comment: @Dave2e: Yes, my bad. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

`as.Date will accept numeric data (the number of days since an epoch), but only if origin is supplied.`

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/as.Date

So if you convert an integer to a date, the integer will count the number of days that have **passed** since the origin, which means the date will be the day **after** the last day has **passed**

An alternative would be to use the Julian date

`as.Date('2005-121', '%Y-%j')`

would yield

`[1] "2005-05-01"`